# Proper rails model namespacing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model, namespaces

Recently I've started a new rails project just for fun and decided to use namespacing in models. And I have some difficulties.

For example, I have model `Party`:

```
# app/models/party.rb

class Party < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

And each party will have `Chat`:

```
# app/models/party/chat.rb

module Party
  class Chat < ActiveRecord::Base
  end
end
```

The question is when I call `Party` how Rails will figure out if I call `module Party` or `class Party`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed, if you do that, Ruby will complain because `Party` can't be a module and a class at the same time. So at least, `Party` would need to remain a class.

Now as the "Rails way" is concerned, we don't usually subclass our associations (ie. your `Chat` will probably `belong_to` a `Party`), we just put all our models in the root namespace (unless one has a good reason to). So you'd have `Party` at `app/models/party.rb` and `Chat` at `app/models/chat.rb`.

I'm guessing one would make a namespaced subclass `Party::Chat` only if there's a different `::Chat` already present, and even that could lead to trouble with Ruby's constant lookup which is sometimes counter-intuitive.

Comment: Thanks for explanation!

Comment: I understand correctly that for large projects models folder will be really huge?

Comment: Correct. Though a model usually only reflects a table in the DB. The `lib` folder is also expected grow with the size of a project.

Comment: I'm asking because in this [article](http://blog.makandra.com/2014/12/organizing-large-rails-projects-with-namespaces/) author (actually this is a book) show that model namespacing can reduce couplexity of models folder. What do you think of it?

Comment: He's right for a large application. He's also right that ie. an "invoice item" can't exist without an invoice. (The way I've intuitively named it gives a hint) Subclassing will also have an effect on the DB table name which is not exactly easy to change later. However we also have to be conscious about premature optimization, I think that's the main factor I'd consider here.